# Is there any way to sync wifi between devices?

Tags: wi-fi, sync

Are there any apps or methods to sync saved wifi between Android devices? Basically it would remember the wifi name and password if you logged into it once from one device on all devices synced.

Comment: [This question over here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/how-does-android-sync-the-wifi-profiles?rq=1) seems to imply that Android does this already.

Comment: @dotVezz Sure. But Celeritas might wish to do that without involving Google services, e.g. for privacy reasons (remember: Google stores WiFi APNs unencrypted, and you cannot even delete them from their servers).

Answer (score 1):

Wifi credentials are actually not stored very securely at all, (plain text!), but in a system folder, meaning that only a rooted app could access it. Google's backup is your best bet.

It's stored in the `data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file, for the record.

If your phone is rooted, there are apps like [Wifi Key Recovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.wifiKeyRecovery)  and [Wifi Password Recovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infowork.wifi.password.recovery) that can get you the keys, but I know of no apps that will automatically sync these as well.

Comment: In newer versions of Android (probably 8+), the file that stores passwords (in plain text) is now `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into Google Services, although my experience is that it sometimes struggles when moving to a new device or if you have multiple devices.

On the device that has the Wi-Fi Settings you want to keep, go to `Settings -> Backup & reset` there is a `Back up my data` option which includes `Backup application data, *Wi-Fi passwords*, and other settings to Google servers`.

Other applications might have a hard time doing this as I would expect Wi-Fi credentials to be securely stored, like passwords.  That might mean root enabled applications can do it but I do not know of any.